# Aumentar fonte da lista na Validação de Dados

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Olá, tenho um campo da minha planilha que tem uma lista pela validação de dados, gostaria de saber como faço pra aumentar essa fonte, deixando ela mais visível.

OBS: Sem o esquema do zoom.

Essa é a lista:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Estava publicando uma resposta quando atualizou... sem zoom acho difícil. A não ser que use um _combobox_

Comment: Eu esqueci de acrescentar desculpa, como seria com combobox?

Comment: Zoom - http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal08.html#Larger

Combobox, seria algo assim: `With Worksheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("ComboBox1")
   .Object.Font.Size = 16
End With`

Comment: Aqui um modelo completo: http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal10.html

Answer (score 2):

Leandro infelizmente, você não pode alterar o tamanho ou o estilo da fonte em uma lista suspensa criada usando a validação de dados.

Você pode estilizar o texto em uma caixa de combinação, no entanto você pode utilizar uma caixa de combinação do controle ActiveX alterando as propriedades 'Font' e 'ListFillRange' você alcançará o desejado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]